# LNK 2019 Error when trying to overload the "<<" opeartor

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a template class `MGraph<T>`with a member function `print_relation` and a friend function which is `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MGraph<T>& other)`

I follwed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx) and wrote this code:

```
template<class T>
ostream& MGraph<T>::print_relation(ostream& os) const
{
    for (VertexId i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
    {
        for (VertexId j = 0; j < max_size; j++)
        {
            os << relation[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
...
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MGraph<T>& other)
{
    os << other.print_relation(os);
    return os;
}
```

I get the following error when compiling:
`1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class MGraph<bool> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$MGraph@_N@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl exec<bool>(class MGraph<bool> *)" (??$exec@_N@@YAXPAV?$MGraph@_N@@@Z)`

It appears 4 times, once for every data type (`int`, `char`, `double`, `bool`).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where did you put the definition (implementation) of the functions, in a source file or a header file?

Comment: In a header file which is included

Comment: You typically get errors like that if you put the implementation of templated classes and functions in source files. Also see ["Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your overload of `operator<<`, you are doing this

`os << other.print_relation(os);`

And since `MGraph<T>::print_relation` returns `std::ostream&`, that is not valid. `operator<<` is not overloaded in such way, that it takes `std::ostream&` on RHS.

So, just remove the `os <<`.

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MGraph<T>& other)
{
    other.print_relation(os);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
So do I need to pass the parameter `os`?

Comment: Never mind. I removed the declaration of `operator<<` as a friend function in the class and now it works.